Is it possible to sort a Dynarray in OCaml?
From what I can tell, each data type seems to have its own type-specific .sort implementation. This means that, although the stdlib Dynarray uses Array as a backing, I can't actually use the Array.sort function.
Is there any canonical way to generally sort structures like I would with C++'s std::sort? Is there some Dynarray.sort that I just am unable to find?
Otherwise, I'm aware of other Dynarray implementations such as those in Batteries, but they don't appear to contain a sort implementation either... I must be missing something as surely I'm not expected to write my own sorting algorithms.

Why Dynarray.sort doesn't exist feels like a question made for octachron to answer.
In the interim, you might convert to an array, sort, then convert back (if further insertion is required).
let dynarray_sort compare arr =
  let arr' = Dynarray.to_array arr in
  Array.sort compare arr';
  Dynarray.of_array arr'

If you need a non-fixed size data structure that is sorted during insertion, you may wish to consider something like a map. Due to maps being backed by a balanced binary search tree, ordering is guaranteed. Access is not O(1) but rather O(log n), but sorting an array is O(n  log n), so if you're doing that frequently, using an array or dynarray may not scale well anyway.
You may have an XY problem here.
If you do want to do an in-place sort on a dynamic array, it's not that difficult using Dynarray.get and Dynarray.set. We'll define a helper function to handle swapping.
let dynarray_swap darr i j =
  Dynarray.(
    let a = get darr i in
    let b = get darr j in
    set darr i b;
    set darr j a
  )

And then a simple bubble sort:
let dynarray_sort compare darr =
  Dynarray.(
    let len = length darr in
    for i = 0 to len - 2 do
      for j = i to len - 2 do
        let a = get darr j in
        let b = get darr (j + 1) in
        let cmp = compare a b in
        if cmp = 1 then dynarray_swap darr j (j + 1)
      done
    done
  )

For reuse you might bundle this up into a module:
module Dynarray_ext = struct
  include Dynarray

  let (.@[]) = get
  let (.@[]<-) = set

  let swap d i j =
    let tmp = d.@[i] in
    d.@[i] <- d.@[j];
    d.@[j] <- tmp

  let bubble_sort cmp d =
    for i = 0 to length d - 2 do
      for j = 0 to length d - 2 - i do
        if cmp d.@[j] d.@[j+1] > 0 then 
          swap d j (j+1)
      done
    done
end


You might want to define access operators to clean up your code. E.g. let (.@[]) = Dynarray.get and let (.@[]<-) = Dynarray.set
